# Men's and women's Chinese names

Tags: names, gender

I wonder, how precisely one can judge by name if the person is a man or woman. I would appreciate the most comprehensive list of attributes which can connote the gender of a person if we see his/her name.
I have never saw any studies regarding the matter.

Comment: A previous girlfriend of mine was named "Army Red" in translation. That single example should suffice to answer your question.

Comment: @倪阔乐 Which character for "red"?

Comment: 。。。。。。肯定就是红军啊。。。

Comment: Actually it is 军红.

Comment: @倪阔乐 then I would guess it's a girl's name because of the x红 pattern. Anyway all is statistics.